# Changing the output of a convolutional layer to a tuple of tensors

Tags: python, image-processing, video, pytorch, conv-neural-network

For processing video frames, I use the squeeze and excitation block for weighting the channels of a convolutional layer.
I want to combine (using torch.stack) the channels(feature maps) of a convolutional layer with the weighted channels (by using the mentioned squeeze and excitation block). But I faced with an error that when using the `torch.stack(x, weighted_channels)` the argument that is related with the convolutional layer's channels`x`, the error says that the `TypeError: stack(): argument 'tensors' (position 1) must be tuple of Tensors, not Tensor`.

```
class conv(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, in_channel, out_channel, out_sigmoid=False):
    super(conv, self).__init__()
            
    self.deconv = self._deconv(in_channel=512, out_channel=256, num_conv=3)
    self.upsample = Upsample(scale_factor=2, mode='bilinear')
    self.SEBlock = SE_Block(c=256)


def _deconv(self, in_channel, out_channel, num_conv=2, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1):
    layers=[]
    layers.append(BasicConv2d(in_channel, out_channel,kernel_size=kernel_size, stride=stride, padding=padding))
    for i in range(1, num_conv):
        layers.append(_SepConv2d(out_channel, out_channel,kernel_size=kernel_size, stride=stride, padding=padding))
    return nn.Sequential(*layers)

   def forward(self, x):
   
    x=self.deconv(x)
    x = self.upsample(x)
    stack = torch.stack(x, self.SEBlock(x,c=256))
    return x



    class BasicConv2d(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, in_planes, out_planes, kernel_size, stride, padding=0):
    super(BasicConv2d, self).__init__()
    self.conv = nn.Conv2d(in_planes, out_planes, kernel_size=kernel_size, stride=stride, padding=padding, bias=False)
    self.bn = nn.BatchNorm2d(out_planes, eps=1e-3, momentum=0.001, affine=True)
    self.relu = nn.ReLU()

def forward(self, x):
    x = self.conv(x)
    x = self.bn(x)
    x = self.relu(x)
    return x

 class _SepConv2d(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, in_planes, out_planes, kernel_size, stride, padding=0):
    super(_SepConv2d, self).__init__()
    self.conv_s = nn.Conv2d(in_planes, out_planes, kernel_size=kernel_size, stride=stride,       padding=padding, bias=False, groups=in_planes)
    self.bn_s = nn.BatchNorm2d(out_planes)
    self.relu_s = nn.ReLU()

    self.conv_t = nn.Conv2d(out_planes, out_planes, kernel_size=1, stride=1, padding=0, bias=False)
    self.bn_t = nn.BatchNorm2d(out_planes)
    self.relu_t = nn.ReLU()

def forward(self, x):
    x = self.conv_s(x)
    x = self.bn_s(x)
    x = self.relu_s(x)

    x = self.conv_t(x)
    x = self.bn_t(x)
    x = self.relu_t(x)
    return x 

class SE_Block(nn.Module):
"credits: https://github.com/moskomule/senet.pytorch/blob/master/senet/se_module.py#L4"
def __init__(self, c, r=16):
    super().__init__()
    self.squeeze = nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d(1)
    self.excitation = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(c, c // r, bias=False),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.Linear(c // r, c, bias=False),
        nn.Sigmoid()
    )

def forward(self, x):
    bs, c, _, _ = x.shape
    y = self.squeeze(x).view(bs, c)
    y = self.excitation(y).view(bs, c, 1, 1)
    return x * y.expand_as(x)
```

I checked two arguments of `torch.stack` but the both are of the same size.

Comment: torch.stack( ( x, weighted_channels ) )  ?

Comment: Please accept the answer if it fixed the problem and provided sufficient explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.stack.html.

`torch.stack(tensors, dim=0, *, out=None) → Tensor`

- `tensors (sequence of Tensors) – sequence of tensors to concatenate`

A sequences of tensors can be a tuple like `(tensor1, tensor2, tensor3)` or a list `[tensor1, tensor2, tensor3]`. What you did is input `x` which is a tensor instead of a sequence of tensors and `weighted_channels` as the dim parameter into the function.

So as noted in the comments either
`torch.stack((x, weighted_channels))` or `torch.stack([x, weighted_channels])` should work.

Keep in mind that this is the same for all functions which take an arbitrary number of tensors and does something with them, e.g. `torch.cat` and all other stack functions like `vstack`, `hstack`-